# Is $\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)} = \frac{-\infty}{-\infty} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponentiation

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sin(x)^\frac{1}{\ln(x)} = ... = 
\exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x}) + \ln(x)}{\ln(x)}\right)$$

Now, from continuity we can evaluate each term separately.

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln(\frac{\sin x}{x}) = 0$

Therefore, we have:
$$\exp \left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}\right)$$

Technically, we have in the exponent $\frac{t}{t} = 1$, where $t=\ln(x)$.
$e$ is indeed the answer, but are we allowed to do this direct arithmetic operation?
I mean, shouldn't it be solved using L'Hôpital's rule if we want to be rigorous?

I'm asking that because my instructor marked $\checkmark$ on this and didn't mention something is wrong about this.

**So, I'm actually asking:** When are we allowed to do this kind of operation?

**Update:**
Isn't it like claiming that $$\frac{-\infty}{-\infty} = 1$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify ${\ln x} / {\ln x}$ to $1$ *before* taking the limit, and therefore there's no problem. But writing ${-\infty}/{-\infty}$ is nonsense.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The L'Hôpital's rule isn't more rigorous than others, nay, mathematicians generally prefer not to use this rule because it is seen as a mechanical way to solve a limit. Furthermore the rule, if it is used mechanically, not always allows to solve a limit. For example, with the limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
this rule fails.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am still not sure why can I claim that $\frac{t}{t}=1$ where $t\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: it can be simplified regardless of the value of t